# HANA sql - unable to use sequence number within subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, sequence, hana

Using SAP Hana Studio, I am trying to use the id of the last inserted row. The error I get is "feature not supported. sequence number not allowed here".

```
INSERT INTO RI_PORTFOLIO.GAR_ESTUDOS VALUES
                            (SEQ_ID_ESTUDO.NEXTVAL,
                             9, 10, 'RI_PORTFOLIO.ATRIBUTOS_DE_UC', NULL, 11);

SELECT * FROM RI_PORTFOLIO.GAR_ESTUDOS WHERE ID_ESTUDO = (SELECT TOP 1 SEQ_ID_ESTUDO.CURRVAL FROM RI_PORTFOLIO.GAR_ESTUDOS);
```

How else can I pick up the last inserted id? I am not familiar with the Hana dialect.

Comment: did you try `WHERE ID_ESTUDO = SEQ_ID_ESTUDO.CURRVAL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the sequence in a select statement or in a where clause. I also just discovered this today!

Check this page for more information about where you can and cannot use the sequence CURRVAL or NEXTVAL.

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/d509277519101489029c064d468c5d/content.htm

Perhaps find the current sequence value and use it to populate a local variable and then use that in your where statement. That might do as a workaround?